# How to use srcset image attribute?

Tags: html, responsive-design

Just came to know about the srcset attribute. I am trying to run it without any success. I expect to see at least 1 image loading in when I run it on Google Chrome for IPhone or IPad but nothing is displayed.

```
<img srcset="img1.png 1x low-bandwidth, img2.png 2x high-bandwidth">
```

Comment: I didnt notice the date

Comment: And it is not widely supported yet, not by all major browsers even: Check out my blog post about the best solution until it gets widely supported: http://blog.benmarten.me/best-way-to-optimize-website-images-for-all-possible-retina-sizes/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>[According to the w3c](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/srcset/w3c-srcset/), the srcset attribute is still in draft status. That means that it is not yet recommended to use it because the specification can still change and web browsers are not expected to implement it already.</strike>

[The scrset attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739625/img-srcset-and-sizes-attributes) is now supported by most browsers. But `low-bandwidth` and `high-bandwidth` are not part of the specification. Likely because it's hard to find an objective definition of "low" and "high" bandwidth which will still be reasonable in ten years. So you can not expect these to have any effect at all.

Answer (score 5):

The first `srcset` implementation has just landed in WebKit, see [announcement post](https://www.webkit.org/blog/2910/improved-support-for-high-resolution-displays-with-the-srcset-image-attribute/).

Answer (score 3):

It's in the v34 beta of chrome, right now v33 is the stable version.

So if nothing is changed it'll be in chrome very soon.

---

I ran this test on v34 and it worked as intended - and even had the bonus of showing high-res images with zoom level at 200 which I wasn't expecting (but pretty obvious now I think about it). You can of course inspect the element and make changes in real time, and zoom in the browser if you don't have a high-res screen.

```
<img src="unsupported.jpg" 
     srcset="cat@1x.jpg 1x,cat@2x.jpg 2x" width="100" height="100">
```

- So pre v34 versions of Chrome you'll ALWAYS see `unsupported.jpg`
- v34 or later you'll see `cat@1x.jpg` for normal screens and `cat@2x.jpg` for high-res
- Of course you'd normally put `cat@1x.jpg` as the standard `src` attribute, this is just for demo.

Remember this won't work on iPad / iPhone yet :-(

Answer (score 2):

The `srcset` attribute is not yet implemented in any browser.

Also - The `low-bandwidth`/`high-bandwidth` parts in your example are not part of any spec or proposal related to `srcset`.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox is not gonna support it in the near future. You can find it's support here. [Srcset support in different browsers](http://caniuse.com/srcset)

There is no high-bandwidth and low-bandwidth elements in this attribute. We need the url, the width of the target device, as you can find it here.

```
<img src="fallback.jpg" srcset="small.jpg 640w 1x, small-hd.jpg 640w 2x, large.jpg 1x,      large-hd.jpg 2x" alt="…">
```

It can be used with the picture element of HTML5. If you're interested in knowing in details about it, read this article. 
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/21/webkit-implements-srcset-and-why-its-a-good-thing/

Answer (score 1):

In short, `Srcset` is a new attribute which allows you to specify different kind of images for different screen-sizes/orientation/display-types. The usage is really simple, you just provide a lot of different images separating them with a comma like this: `<img src="image.jpg" alt="image" srcset="<img> <descriptor>, ..., <img_n> <descriptor_n>">`. Here is an example: `srcset="image.jpg 160w, image2.jpg 320w, image3.jpg 2x"`

---

This is a longer answer which explains things in more details.

First of all you miss required `src` attribute as `srcset` only enhance img tag.

**Difference between srcset and picture**. Both `srcset` and `picture` does approximately the same things, but there is a subtle difference: `picture` dictates what image the browser should use, whereas `srcset` gives the browser a choice. A lot of things can be used to select this choice like viewport size, users preferences, network condition and so on. The support for `srcset` is pretty good and [almost all current browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset) more or less support it. Situation with a `picture` element is a [little bit worse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=picture).

**Descriptors** are just a way to show what kind of image is hidden behind the resource. There are various kinds of descriptors:

- **density descriptor**. `srcset="image.jpg, image-2X.jpg 2x"`
  The display density values—the 1x, 2x, etc.—are referred to as display density descriptors. If a display density descriptor isn’t provided, it is assumed to be 1x. Good variant to target retina displays.
- **width descriptor**. `srcset="image-240.jpg 240w, image-640.jpg 640w"`. I am sure this is self explanatory. The only problem is that by itself width descriptor is not really helpful. [Why? read here](http://blog.cloudfour.com/responsive-images-101-part-4-srcset-width-descriptors/)
- **size descriptor**, which only makes sense if you use width descriptor. `srcset="image-160.jpg 160w, image-320.jpg 320w, image-640.jpg 640w, image-1280.jpg 1280w" sizes="(max-width: 480px) 100vw, (max-width: 900px) 33vw, 254px">`. The instructions for the browser would look like this: `(max-width: 480px) 100vw` — if the viewport is 480 pixels wide or smaller, the image will be 100% of the viewport width. `(max-width: 900px) 33vw` — if the viewport is 480 pixels wide or smaller, this rule will never be reached because of the previous media condition. And 254px is when there is no media condition listed, the length is assumed to be a default value used when none of the other media conditions are met.

Just for completeness will add here that there is an [image-set()](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-image-set) attribute for a background image in CSS and some other helpful link [here](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2015/08/the-state-of-responsive-images/)

Answer (score 1):

## Using srcset with sizes

```
<img sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 580px,
      (min-width: 640px) 48vw,
      98vw"
    srcset="img/hello-300.jpg 300w,
      img/hello-600.jpg 600w,
      img/hello-900.jpg 900w,
      img/hello-1200.jpg 1200w"
    src="img/hello-900.jpg" alt="hello">
```

`sizes` are like media queries, describing how much space the image takes of the viewport.

- if viewport is larger than 1200px, image is exactly 580px (for example our content is centered in container which is max 1200px wide. Image takes half of it minus margins).
- if viewport is between 640px and 1200px, image takes 48% of viewport (for example image scales with our page and takes half of viewport width minus margins).
- if viewport is any other size , in our case less than 640px, image takes 98% of viewport (for example image scales with our page and takes full width of viewport minus margins). **Media condition must be omitted for last item.**

`srcset` is just telling the browser what images we have available, and what are their sizes.

- `img/hello-300.jpg` is 300px wide,
- `img/hello-600.jpg` is 600px wide,
- `img/hello-900.jpg` is 900px wide,
- `img/hello-1200.jpg` is 1200px wide

`src` is always mandatory image source. In case of using with `srcset`, `src` will serve fallback image in case browser is not supporting `srcset`.

## Using srcset without sizes

```
<img src="img/hello-300.jpg" alt="hello"
     srcset="img/hello-300.jpg 1x, 
       img/hello-600.jpg 2x,
       img/hello-1200.jpg 3x">
```

`srcset` provides list of available images, with device-pixel ratio `x` descriptor.

- if device-pixel ratio is 1, use `img/hello-300.jpg`
- if device-pixel ratio is 2, use `img/hello-600.jpg`
- if device-pixel ratio is 3, use `img/hello-1200.jpg`

`src` is always mandatory image source. In case of using with `srcset`, `src` will serve fallback image in case browser is not supporting `srcset`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `<picture>` with `srcset` as described [here](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_picture) – with which, personally, I've had better experience.

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 1200px)" srcset="img/hello-1200.jpg" />
    <source media="(min-width: 900px)" srcset="img/hello-900.jpg" />
    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img/hello-600.jpg" />
    <img src="img/hello-300.jpg" />
</picture>
```