# Img srcset and sizes attributes

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple website with `img` tag, that will use the new `srcset` attribute. The main idea is to change the image (src) depending on the screen resolution.

[Working example](http://pixelteam.pl/surprise/some/files/index.html)

The problem is with the `sizes`. As you can see, now it is 100vw, but it doesn't work correctly. For me, it resize img to about 80% of the screen, not 100%. 
The best thing is, that when I write in CSS for `img` tag `width: 100vw`, it will resize to 100% of the screen.

Can someone help me with that? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Here is a very useful albeit long article http://ericportis.com/posts/2014/srcset-sizes/

Comment: It would be useful to include the code sample in the original question. I had the same question, but don't now know what was the erroneous value..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image is 1152 pixels wide, but you tell the browser it is 1500 pixels wide (`1500w`).
The browser then determines the image's density based on what you told it, and corrects the image's intrinsic dimensions accordingly, but since it used the wrong value for the density calculations, the image occupies 76.8% of the viewport width rather than 100% of it.

To change that, you can provide the browser with a larger resource, or tell it that the resource is `1152w`.

Comment: Thanks, I had a similar problem that drove me nuts.  The moral of the story - make sure the widths you specify in srcset match the widths of the images exactly.